# How to hard code a string to a property of an object?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to hard code a string to a property of an object?

```
   public TextLine TextLine1
    {
        get
        {
            return TextLineObj;
        }
        set
        {


            TextLineObj = value;
            this.TextLine1.Name = "TextLine1";
        }
    }
```

Can any help me to correct this code?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please clarify.

Comment: What do you mean under hard coding to property of an object?

Comment: it's very ambiguous and hard to figure out from code as to what you're trying to achieve, please try ans put it in words.

Comment: I got different classes using same named properties like TextLine1,TextLine2,.... The number of textLines vary for different classes. I'm here trying to databind a listbox with the hardcoded name of these properties. This hard coding cannot be done from UI page. Is there any way to do it within the class itself?.

Comment: Is it that you're trying to hardcode the string to the *name of the property*?

Comment: I need to hard code a text to the property textLine1 which is another object of the class TextLine.

Answer (score 1):

change the set to

```
set
{
  value.Name = "HardCoded";
  TextLineObj = value; //TextLineObj should be _textLine
}
```